# How to install old 32bit packages (i686) on CentOS 7.6

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum

I have an application that requires following packages to be installed via yum: openmotif.i686, libusb.i686 and libXpm.i686

On CentOS 6 is was just fine to install those packages before installing my application. 
However when trying the same on CentOS 7 these packages cannot be found. When downloading and manually installing those packages it requires some more dependencies to be installed. And then those dependencies have more dependencies and so on. It seems like an endless loop.

Is there an easy way to install those packages with all its dependencies on CentOS 7.6?

Answer (score 2):

yes, exactly like you'd install any other package: `yum install openmotif.i686 libusb.i686 libXpm.i686` will automatically install all dependencies.

You should basically never manually download packages.

In your case, `openmotif` is called `motif`:

```
$> repoquery --whatprovides openmotif
motif-0:2.3.4-14.el7_5.x86_64
motif-0:2.3.4-14.el7_5.i686
```

but `libusb.i686` and `libXpm.i868` are most certainly available on CentOS 7. I've tried it:

```
yum install libusb.i686 motif.i686 libXpm.i686
```

just works.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried but these packages are not available on CentOS 7. That's why I continued with trying to install the rpm's after downloading them.

Comment: @Qowaz not true: on a clean CentOS 7 container, I can install libusb.i686 and libXpm.i686; openmotif got renamed. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I just tried again, but when I do `yum install libusb.i686` I get "No package libusb.i686 available". It is checking in c7-local and c7-local-updates.

Comment: @Qowaz sorry, then there's something wrong with your CentOS setup. As said, on a clean installation, this works. See my [recording starting from a clean CentOS 7](https://asciinema.org/a/332H3tRLciGozzBM9tbJQXO3V); I update first (as a matter of habit), and then just `yum install libusb.i686` and it works beautifully.